# WebGL context can't render simplest screen

Tags: opengl-es, rendering, webgl

I'm stuck trying to render some extremely basic stuff on webgl, I've dumbed down the rendering to the most basic thing I can think of in order to find where the issue lies, but I can't even draw a simple square for some reason. The scene I really want to render is more complex, but as I said, I've dumbed it down to try to find the problem and still no luck. I'm hoping someone can take a look and find whatever I'm missing, wich I assume is a setup step at some point.

The gl commands I'm running (as reported by webgl inspector, without errors) are:

1. clearColor(0,0,0,1)
2. clearDepth(1)
3. clear(COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
4. useProgram([Program 2])
5. bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, [Buffer 5])
6. vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
7. drawArrays(TRIANGLES, 0, 6)

The buffer that is being used there (Buffer 5) is setup as follows:

```
bufferData(ARRAY_BUFFER, [-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1], STATIC_DRAW)
```

And the program (Program 2) data is:

- LINK_STATUS true
- VALIDATE_STATUS false
- DELETE_STATUS false
- ACTIVE_UNIFORMS 0
- ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES 1

Vertex shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

attribute vec2 aPosition;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0, 1);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

Other state I think could be relevant:

- CULL_FACE    false
- CULL_FACE_MODE   BACK
- FRONT_FACE   CCW
- BLEND    false
- DEPTH_TEST   false
- VIEWPORT 0, 0 640 x 480
- SCISSOR_TEST false
- SCISSOR_BOX  0, 0 640 x 480
- COLOR_WRITEMASK  true,true,true,true
- DEPTH_WRITEMASK  true
- STENCIL_WRITEMASK    0xffffffff
- FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING  null

What I expected to see from that setup/commands is a red quad taking up the whole clip space, but what I see is simply the cleared screen, as the drawArrays doesn't seem to be doing anything. Can anybody spot what I'm missing? Any tips on how to debug this would be very welcome too!

Comment: Not sure if this is actually the problem here, but regardless you're missing a world-space -> clip-space transformation in your vertex shader. Basically, you need to multiply your input vertex data with a special (model-view-)projection matrix. See [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html).

Comment: @elmov Thanks for the input. My shader was initially doing that but I removed it trying to rule out the problem was on my transformation matrices. AFAIK, the code above should be rendering fine within the clip space as the vertex go from -1 to +1 (and I believe the clipspace is exactly from (-1, -1) to (1, 1), do you know if this is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @user1724911's fiddle, I found out what I missed is enabling the vertex attribute array - stupidly simple mistake. I'm actually surprised I didn't get any warning from webgl inspector about this, but the solution was simply to add a call to enable that attribute:

```
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.attributes.aPosition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
bufferData(ARRAY_BUFFER, [-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1], STATIC_DRAW)
```

replace to:

```
bufferData(ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1]), STATIC_DRAW)
```

Because webgl doesn't know which type you are passing here (integer or float or byte). Example:

http: jsfiddle.net/9QxAz/

Comment: I may not have explained what those commands are clearly, those are what [webgl-inspector](http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/) show on the command trace (so they are 'javascript agnostic'), my actual code is calling Float32Array when pushing the data into the buffer. I'll check your fiddle and see if I can spot the difference though, as it seems to be doing pretty much the same as my code is.

Comment: Checking your fiddle, I found out what I'm missing is to enabled the vertex array attribute (enableVertexAttribArray) for my position attribute. Adding that call fixes my problem and I can finally see something! I knew it had to be something simple I missed... Thanks!